# RangeError and rerundering the future builder in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, future, builder, flutter-pageview

I have two problem,I'm using page view builder to build my days,

```
            child: PageView.builder(
              physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: allDays.length,
              controller: _pageController,
              itemBuilder: ( context, int index) {
                return _listDay(index);
              },
            ),
```

every day contain list of times from api,

```
  void initState() {
    _futureTime = getDateDayAPI1.getTimeApi(doctorInfoName, widget.dayName);
    super.initState();
    _futureTime.then((value){
      setState(() {
        _snapshotTimes.addAll(value);
      });
    });
    _future.then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _snapshot.addAll(data);
      });
    },);
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _futureTime,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if (_futureTime == null){
            return Container(
              child: Center(child: loadingRing(),),
            );
          }
          else {
            return SizedBox(
              width: 150,
              height: 180,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 6,
                itemBuilder:  (context, index) {
                  return index == 0 ? Container() : _listItem(index-1);
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    );
}
```

the first problem is the widget rebuild it self on scrolling,
the seconde that it show the error in this picture
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the list being loaded `_futureTime` in this case could cause an error like this if the list itself has an internal error. An example would be a `getDateDayAPI1.getTimeApi(doctorInfoName, widget.dayName);` could have a list inside of it that is actually throwing an index error. `FutureBuilder` tends to hide these errors. Worth mentioning and hopefully saves someone time